# How to use function interface with diff implementation

Tags: go, interface

Im using `interface` which I want to **mock** one method in it  `function1` in test and I wasn't able to figure it out how is the best to do it that for prod code it will provide 1 value and for test provide some mock value , can someone please give example ? (edited)
this is the code:

https://play.golang.org/p/w367IOjADFV

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type vInterface interface {
    function1() bool
}

type mStruct struct {
    info string
    time time.Time
}

func (s *mStruct) function1() bool {
    return true
}

func callSomething(si vInterface) bool {
    return si.function1()
}

func (s *mStruct) vl1() bool {
    s.time = time.Now()
    s.info = "vl1->info"
    return callSomething(s)
}

var currentVt1 mStruct

func main() {
    vl1 := currentVt1.vl1()

    fmt.Println(vl1)
}
```

**The test is like this**

```
func Test_callSomething(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        si vInterface
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want bool
    }{
        {
            name: "my tests",
            args: args{

            },
            want: false,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := callSomething(tt.args.si); got != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("callSomething() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

But not sure how to mock it right ...

**update**

```
func Test_mStruct_vl1(t *testing.T) {
    type fields struct {
        info string
        time time.Time
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name   string
        fields fields
        want   bool
    }{
        {
            name: "some test",
            fields: struct {
                info string
                time time.Time
            }{info: "myinfo", time: time.Now() },

        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            s := &mStruct{
                info: tt.fields.info,
                time: tt.fields.time,
            }
            if got := s.vl1(); got != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("vl1() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. What do you want to mock? `mStruct.function1()` returns `true` in your code. You want it to return `false` during the test?

Comment: @icza - I want to test function `callSomething` with different implementations for `function1` sometime with true and sometime with false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a type (any type) that implements the `vInterface` interface. Here's a simple example:

```
type mockedVInterface struct {
    value bool
}

func (m mockedVInterface) function1() bool {
    return m.value
}
```

This is a simple enough implementation which we can control: we can tell what its `function1()` function should return by simply setting that value to its `value` field.

This `mockedVInterface` type is created solely for testing purposes, the production code does not need it. Put it in the same file where you have the test code (put it before `Test_callSomething()`).

And here's the testing code:

```
func Test_callSomething(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        si vInterface
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want bool
    }{
        {
            name: "testing false",
            args: args{
                si: mockedVInterface{value: false},
            },
            want: false,
        },
        {
            name: "testing true",
            args: args{
                si: mockedVInterface{value: true},
            },
            want: true,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := callSomething(tt.args.si); got != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("callSomething() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Note that in this simple case we could also use a simple non-struct type that has `bool` as its underlying type like this:

```
type mockedVInterface bool

func (m mockedVInterface) function1() bool {
    return bool(m)
}
```

And it works and testing code is also simpler:

```
tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want bool
    }{
        {
            name: "testing false",
            args: args{
                si: mockedVInterface(false),
            },
            want: false,
        },
        {
            name: "testing true",
            args: args{
                si: mockedVInterface(true),
            },
            want: true,
        },
    }
```

But this only works if the mockable interface has a single function with a single return value. In the general case a struct is needed.

Comment: Thanks, sorry what is `mockedVInterface` and where should I put it in the tests ? if so can you provide the full code ?

Comment: `mockedVInterface` is a new type created solely for testing purposes. You may simply put it in the same test file where you have `Test_callSomething()`.

Comment: ok I put it inside the test function but I got error for function `func (m mockedVInterface) function1() bool {
    return m.value
}`

Comment: @JhonD You can't put it _inside_ a function, put it _before_ the function. You can't define methods inside a function.

Comment: thanks, 1+ , can you please explain why you use mock interface instead of mock function ?

Comment: @JhonD Because as you said, you want to test `callSomething()`, and this function takes (requires) a value of interface type `vInterface`. So you must have a mocked implementation of this interface. You can't pass a function value to `callSomething()`, it expects an interface value, so you have to give it that.

Comment: in this way we can achieve the dependency injection like ?does it better approach for testing ?

Comment: @JhonD I'm not sure what you're asking, but yes, using interfaces is one way to handle different implementations of some abstraction the same way.

Comment: I mean something like this ? https://appliedgo.net/di/ ? this is not the same approach ?

Comment: @JhonD I'm sorry, I do not intend to go through that article, therefore cannot answer your question with certainty.

Comment: Sure np, you said that we can use the interface if we only have 1 method, can you please provide example if we have more then one method ?

Comment: @JhonD The first solution using a struct to mock the implementation is a general one, you can use that with interfaces having arbitrary number of methods. The second, more specialized solution is what can only be used with a single method with single return value, as the mocking type is just a single boolean value (which can't "encode" multiple return values).

Comment: Sorry last question which is a bit tricky in this context ... is it possible to call to function `vl1` with mock to the function  `function1` ? please see my update . hope you can help

Comment: should I open new question ?

Comment: I close this question, it will be great if you can have a look at this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098327/mock-inner-function-in-golang